# Java wait for button press before continue

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

Im trying to make a GUI Class for settings in a game, it is it's own class apart from main. in main i instantiate an object of the settings class, and i want it to wait until it takes a click before continuing the code in main. as it is, it instantiates the object and finishes the code in main without waiting for input. ive tried actionListener but cant get it to work, my guess is because i have the GUI separate from main.

settings class

```
public class Settings extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private int option;

public Settings()
{
    option = 0;
    //JFrame
    setTitle("Battleship Settings");
    setVisible(true);
    int xInset = getInsets().left + getInsets().right; //right left window borders
    int yInset = getInsets().top + getInsets().bottom; //top bottom window borders
    setSize(300 + xInset, 300 + yInset);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); //center window

    //Main Panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setSize(300, 300);
    panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    add(panel);

    // Creation of a Panel to contain the Buttons.
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
    buttonPanel.setLocation(0, 0);
    buttonPanel.setSize(300, 300);
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    panel.add(buttonPanel);

    //Buttons
    JButton b1 = new JButton("VS AI");
    b1.setSize(180, 30);
    int b1CenterX = (int) ((buttonPanel.getSize().getWidth() / 2) - (b1.getSize().getWidth() /2));
    b1.setLocation(b1CenterX, 145);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(b1);

    JButton b2 = new JButton("2 Players");
    b2.setSize(180, 30);
    int b2CenterX = (int) ((buttonPanel.getSize().getWidth() / 2) - (b2.getSize().getWidth() /2));
    b2.setLocation(b2CenterX, 195);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(b2);

    panel.setOpaque(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //if you dont exit on close, the program keeps running on the background
}

public int getOption()
{
    return option;
}

public void setOption(int optn)
{
    option = optn;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getActionCommand().matches("VS AI"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "VS AI");
        option = 1;
        this.dispose();
    }
    else if (e.getActionCommand().matches("2 Players"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2 Players");
        option = 2;
        this.dispose();
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong");
}

}
```

and this is main

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Settings BattleSettings = new Settings();



    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "option # " +BattleSettings.getOption());
}

}
```

the program is firing the MessageDialog in main before it has given the player a chance to select a button. i want to wait after the GUI window is created and resume the code once the player has clicked a button.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`.

See [How to make dislaogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

In fact, what you could do, is make your `Settings` class a `JPanel` and add it as the message parameter to a `JOptionPane` instead.

For [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features)

This will allow the `Settings` class to be more flexible and be more reusable in more ways...

Answer (score 0):

how about putting that line inside the `actionPerformed` function, like:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getActionCommand().matches("VS AI"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "VS AI");
        option = 1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "option # " +option);
        this.dispose();
    }
    else if (e.getActionCommand().matches("2 Players"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2 Players");
        option = 2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "option # " +option);
        this.dispose();
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong");
}
```

so that line will be called definitely after you choose `vs AI` or `2 players`

**EDIT**:

okay, I suggest you follow @MadProgrammer 's solution.. I also think that using `JDialog` is the right way..

Comment: i put it on main, because i will have some code in main after the click button. the idea is take the click and if you selected Vs AI, to start the game that will be coded in main.

Comment: no, the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "option # " + option); code runs before you can select anything.

Comment: you already remove your `setVisible(true)` in the constructor..?